# Constants in probability function, e.g. P(cX = cx). What happens to them?

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm studying the theorems that show the fashion in which translating or scaling a random variable by a constant changes the expected value. In these proofs, I've seen constants used within probability functions, e.g.
$$E[X+c] = \sum_{x} (x+c)P(X+c=x+c)$$
$$E[X+c] = \sum_{x} xP(X=x) + \sum_{x} cP(X=x)$$
$$E[X+c] = E[X] +c$$

Or similarly, $E[cX] = \sum_{x} cxP(cX=cx)=c\sum_{x} xP(X=x)=cE[X]$.

My question is, why does the constant, $c$, disappear in $P(X+c=x+c)$ and $P(cX=cx)$? Are we simply cancelling the $c$ with a subtraction ($X+c-c=x+c-c$) and division ($\frac{cX}{c}=\frac{cx}{c}$), in each example, respectively? Or is there another explanation?

Comment: Yes, $X+c = x+c \iff X=x$ and $cX = c x \iff X=x$ for $c \neq 0$.

Comment: @MathLover So we can apply the laws of algebra to the variables of a probability function?

Comment: Please be careful not to over-generalize. The events before and after algebraic manipulation have to be the same. For example, $\{X^2 < c^2\}$ may or may not be the same as $\{X < c\},$ depending on the support of $X.$